# Flutter: Como superponer teclado

Tags: flutter

Estoy trabajando con un sistema de login y cuando voy a escribir usuario y la contrasena el teclado del celular superpone los TextField de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede solucionar?

Comment: falta mas información, pero lo mas probable, es que los objetos posteriores al TextField están desbordados en el alineamiento X.  Si compartes el código se puede verificar y validar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones:

1- Usando `ListView` como parent de tus widgets.

```
        ListView(
              children: [
                FlutterLogo(),
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
              ],
            );
```

2- Usando `SingleChildScrollView` como parent de tu widget `Column`.

```
        SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  FlutterLogo(),
                  TextField(),
                  TextField(),
                  TextField(),
                ],
              ),
            );
```